# Making a contiguous matrix variable using STL container

Tags: c++, stl

I am looking for a way to have a Matrix variable (i.e, a bunch of ordered column vectors) which is contiguous in memory, using an STL container (e.g, an std::vector). One option is this:

```
vector< vector<float> > mat;
mat.push_back (column1); // column1 is of type vector<float> 
mat.push_back (column2); // column2 is of type vector<float>
```

which is not contiguous in the sense that `&mat[1][0]` is not equal to `&mat[0][N-1] + 1`, where `N` is the length of `column1`.

Another option is this:

```
vector< float > mat;
float f1[] = {1., 2., 3.};
float f2[] = {4., 5., 6.};
mat.insert (mat.end (), f1, f1 + 3);
mat.insert (mat.end (), f2, f2 + 3);
```

Which is contiguous in memory, but enforces me to use an array of floats.

**EDIT**

TO make it clear, I prefer an option like `vector < vector<float> >`, so I can access a given column as an STL vector.

Comment: And shouldn't it be `mat.insert (mat.end (), f2, f2 + 3);`?

Comment: Why does it have to be contiguous in memory?

Comment: The question is, is there another option I am missing, which gives me what I want

Comment: @Andreas Brinck: yes, thanks. copy/paste error (I edited it)

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: Because the matrix is an input to an existing algorithm which assumes contiguous input.

Comment: One problem here is that it allows for columns of different length. That would make foe a difficult to handle matrix.

Comment: @juanchopanza: That's true, I'd have to enforce constant column length somehow (like making my own matrix class, as suggested by Andreas Brinck)

Comment: Plus, the actual data won be contiguous either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write my own matrix class which uses a `std::vector<float>` as backend for storage.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this trivially with the standard library as far as I know, but you could always use Boost's [multidimensional arrays](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Subclass a `vector<float>`. Make of of size `rowSize*colSize`. The memory is contiguous since it is one single vector.

For the part on accessing columns as vectors, consider instead, accessing columns using two iterators to mark the range of the column. Modify your algorithms on columns to work with `RandomAccessIterator` conforming iterators, or wrap the two iterators using a `Column` class that computes the address from the start iterator in `T& operator[](size_t)`.

Comment: Don't derive from a standard class, though, use composition.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that the data is indeed contiguous, I think you need to base it on a single array-type object, with static or dynamic size depending on your requirements, and take care of all the book-keeping and access. Have a look at [boost matrices](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm). A while back I worked on [static-sized matrices](http://project-mathlibs.web.cern.ch/project-mathlibs/sw/html/SMatrix.html) and although I don't suggest that you use that stuff, it is an (old.fashioned) example of how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

See if [this](https://msmvps.com/blogs/gdicanio/archive/2010/12/28/a-simple-2d-matrix-class.aspx) helps you (probably you have to modify the source code if you want column-major storage).